# how to select two record from 1 table and insert that record to another table

Tags: asp.net

i want to take two record from 1 table and insert that record to another table with the ID already store in the 2nd Table, look at the example below.

[image]

when you look to the table there are images uploaded against tracking ID now i want to insert more images against that tracking and that createDate and Project_ID comes From Another Table

here is my store procedure

```
create proc spinsertMoreImages
@TrackerID int ,
@PhotoName varchar(50),
@PhotoDynamicName varchar(50) ,
@IsActive bit = null

as
begin
            insert into tblFilePhoto (Tracker_ID , Photo_Name , CreateDate , Project_ID  , PhotoDynamicName ,  IsActive)

         select LetterCreateDate, Project_Id from tblFileTracker where Tracker_ID = @TrackerID;     
end
```

and here is my Aspx.cs Code

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clsFileTracker objLetter = new clsFileTracker();
            foreach (HttpPostedFile htfiles in uplImage.PostedFiles)
            {
                var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
                var path = guid.ToString() + ".jpg";
                StrName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(htfiles.FileName);
                htfiles.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/upload/") + path);
                objLetter.SaveMoreImage(StrName, txtLetterCreateDate.Text, ddlProject.SelectedValue, path);
            }
```

and here is my .cs Code

```
public void saveMoreImage( string StrName, string LetterCreatDate, string ProjectID , string path)
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("spinsertMoreImages", conn);
            cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrackerID", fID);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhotoName", StrName);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", LetterCreatDate);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ProjectID);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhotoDynamicName", path);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

here is a problem with @createDate and @ProjectID how we insert these two data into another table with the same tracking ID

Thanks